# When creating types at runtime, is it possible to use lambdas?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, runtime, clr

I am trying to create a class and method at runtime, that should implement a given interface. I am using [Castle.DynamicProxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/README.md) nuget package for this purpose.

This is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var proxymaker = new ProxyMaker<IService>();
        var service = proxymaker.Create();
        var value = service.GetValue();
    }
}


public interface IService
{
    int GetValue();
}

public class ProxyMaker<T> where T : class
{
    public T Create()
    {
        var classEmitter = new ClassEmitter(
            new ModuleScope(),
            "ServiceProxy",
            null,
            new[] {typeof (T)});

        var method = classEmitter.CreateMethod("GetValue", typeof (int));

        method.CodeBuilder.AddStatement(new ReturnStatement(new ConstReference(7)));

        var type = classEmitter.BuildType();

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return (T)instance;
    }
}
```

As you can see, while creating a method, I am just returning a constant int of 7. I want to add a method body there with logic, but the api is not so friendly. Is there any way I can pass a delegate/anonymous method/ lambda expression to it, which will be used as method body ?

Comment: What is the `ClassEmitter` class? Is it from a third-party library?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, sorry. I should have mentioned I am using Castle.DynamicProxy

Comment: Is `T` in this case the interface you are trying to implement?

Comment: Yes. That's the interface I am trying to implement. The method body is where problem lies. It seems to complicated to add a method body.

Comment: I am updated the questions to include interface too.